# Common java web module for all other applications

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I would like to know, is there any solution for the below requirement.

We have 5 web applications developed in java and each application has a module called users. If any changes came into users module like bug fix or enhancement then all other applications should be changed and each application has duplicate code. Note : we can have the same database tables for these type of common modules for all of the applications and data will be differentiated by having the different schema with same tables or introducing the app_name column in the table such that data will be identified by app_name

Is there any solution such that we build one users module and will be used by all other applications such that any changes into the module also be effected in other applications without redeveloping in all other applications.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "changes in the module"? Data changes or code changes? In the latter case, do the apps work on the same user data?

Comment: It could be bug fix or an enhancement  like adding feature into the module

Comment: @Henry - Yes. we will have common database for all other applications for these type of module.

Comment: Create a **single** separate project for your *users' module* that all of your five web applications would depend on. Currently, how are you packaging your applications? Are you using any kind of building tool?

Comment: @aribeiro - Thanks for comment. Currently we are doing the same, with this there was maintenance will be increased as we need to do update all the other projects. I am looking for a solution where the module will be plugged into application dynamically with technology support, like using web services or any other technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a separate Project for common modules and using the maven WAR overlay feature might be the favourable solution upon deploying the other dependent applications.